# How can I covert the string to list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

My json data looks like:

```
{
 "metadata": [
        "{'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}", 
        "{'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31,}"]    
 }
```

I want my data to look like:

```
{
 "metadata": [
        {'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}, 
        {'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31,}]    
 }
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt. Thanks

Comment: Do you have exactly what you've put as *your .json data* in a file or is this what you have in Python? Because `'` (single quotes) are not valid JSON.

Comment: Maybe use `import ast` `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @Shreestina Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @oda It didn't work.

Comment: @Shreestina Can you maybe type `print(repr(x))` and show me what the output is? `x` I am assuming is your data.

Comment: {"metadata": ["{'Node_id': 38, 'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimump ressure': -22.03 }", "{'Node_id': 39, 'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31}" ], "names": [ "38", "39"] }

Comment: @Shreestina Sorry for the late reply I was not notified. Simply apply my answer **without** executing the statement `d = literal_eval(s)`. If you do not want to convert "38" and "39" (in the list corresponding to key "names") to integers, then simply do `d['metadata'] = [literal_eval(item) for item in d['metadata']]` to only change the value associated with "metadata". Does that solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

arr = [
 '{"Node_id": 38,"Maxpressure": -10.97, 
    "Minimum_pressure": -22.03}', 
 '{"Node_id": 39,"Maxpressure": 28.83, 
    "Minimum_pressure": 10.31}'
]

res_arr = []
for obj in arr:
   y = json.loads(obj)
   res_arr.append(y)

print(res_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string looks like

```
s = """
{
 "metadata": [
        "{'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}",
        "{'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31,}"]
 }
"""
```

then you can get your desired output using `literal_eval` from the `ast` module.

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = literal_eval(s)
# iterate over keys of dictionary d
for key in d:
    d[key] = [literal_eval(item) for item in d[key]]

print(d)
```

**Notes**

---

- `literal_eval(s)` returns a dictionary

```
{'metadata': ["{'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': "
              '-22.03}',
              "{'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': "
              '10.31,}']}
```

- We iterate over the keys of the dictionary `d` just in case your actual data has more than just one `key` in the dictionary. In the sample input provided, there is only one key, `"metadata"`.
- `d[key]` is currently a list of strings.
- We replace `d[key]` with a new list formed by applying `literal_eval` to each string in `d[key]`.

**Output**

---

```
{'metadata': [{'Maxpressure': -10.97,
               'Minimum_pressure': -22.03,
               'Node_id': 38},
              {'Maxpressure': 23.83, 
               'Minimumpressure': 10.31, 
               'Node_id': 39}]}
```

**Warning**

---

You may have noticed that another way to achieve the above would have been to replace all the `literal_eval`'s with `eval`. You **should not** be using the built-in `eval` unless you can be sure that you trust the input source. For this particular application, there is absolutely no need to use `eval` and you can achieve what you want without it. The `literal_eval` option is a safe alternative. From the `literal_eval` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), the function is used to

> [s]afely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
> values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
> oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
> expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the strings in your *metadata* list which is easily done with:

```
from ast import literal_eval

J = {
    "metadata": [
        "{'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}", 
        "{'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31,}"]    
 }

P = {'metadata': [literal_eval(s) for s in J['metadata']]}

print(P)
```

**Output:**

```
{'metadata': [{'Node_id': 38, 'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}, {'Node_id': 39, 'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

if You want convert json data into python dicionary.

first you declear metadata as variable
after then use

```
json.loads(metadata)
```

this is method in which you get your data from json to dictionary.

Comment: This is true, but it will return `{'metadata': ["{'Node_id': 38,'Maxpressure': -10.97, 'Minimum_pressure': -22.03}", "{'Node_id': 39,'Maxpressure': 23.83, 'Minimumpressure': 10.31,}"]}`. Notice how the elements of the list are strings. OP does not want them to be strings.